# Error in x[[i]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

Tags: r, recursion

I'm new to R and stack overflow. I've searched online but couldn't find an answer to my question. I wanted to create a loop that extracts from a list and replaces the entry in the list.

```
(x<-list(1:5,NULL))

  rpl<- function(x){
      for(i in x){
        if(x[[i]]==1)
          x[[i]]<-25
      }

  }
```

Comment: `for (i in x)` iterates over the contents of the list named `x` (internally to the function). The first element in the list is a vector, 1 to 5. In R, the double-bracket can only retrieve a single element, so the index `i` must be of length 1, not 5 as it is in your code. Even if you used `x <- c(1:5, list(NULL))`, when `i` is `NULL`, it will fail. Perhaps you meant `for (i in seq_along(x))`? It will still fail, but differently (and later) :-)

Comment: There is no need to wrap the first line in parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x<-list(1:5,NULL)

lapply(x, function(el) {
    if(is.null(el)) el else {
        ifelse(el %in% 1, 25, el)
    }
    })

#[[1]]
#[1] 25  2  3  4  5

#[[2]]
#NULL
```

use `lapply` to work with and return lists.
It's better to use `%in%` because `==` will fail on missing values.